# Unit Test using MS fakes: HttpClient and await

Tags: c#, unit-testing, httpclient, shim

I have class which creates instance of HttpClient and call some method and returns response in async mode.

For ReadAsAsync, I have used nuget package "System.Net.Http.Formatting".

**Source Code:**

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();       
        public MyClass()
        {
             string myUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyWebAPI"];
             client.BaseAddress = new Uri(myUrl);
        }
        public async Task<List<YourClass>> GetYourClass()
        {
            var filters = "string";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(filters).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var notes = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<YourClass>>();
                return notes;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    public class YourClass
    {
        private string Address { get; set; }

        public YourClass(string address)
        {
            Address = address;
        }       
    }
```

**Unit Test:**

```
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                MyClass obj = new MyClass();
                ShimHttpClient shimHttpClient = new ShimHttpClient();
                ShimHttpClient.Constructor = (t) =>
                {
                    shimHttpClient = new ShimHttpClient();
                    shimHttpClient.GetAsyncString = (a) =>
                    {
                        return new System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>(function1);
                    };
                };
                var returnVal = obj.GetYourClass();
            }
        }

        private System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage function1()
        {
            return new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
        }
    }
```

We can't change the source code. but need to unit test GetAsync and ReadAsAync call through dummy call test.

Comment: Why? Those aren't *your* classes, they are built into .NET. It's like asking how to unit-test `int` or `string`. Are you asking how to *mock* them perhaps, so you can test `MyClass` and `GetYourClass` ?

Comment: how to test those methods

Comment: Don't. You don't need to. You already know what they'll do if the URL is wrong, or if the server returns a response. It's *your code* that needs testing, not .NET's. If you want to mock HttpClient, pass your own HttpMessageHandler to the constructor

Comment: Besides, the code you posted tries to *mock* the classes, not test them. It would be a LOT easier if you injected an HttpMessageHandler in the MyClass constructor, using the default if none is specified. [Check the source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L102).

Comment: @user2323308 Your class is tightly coupled to implementation concerns. Consider reviewing your design choice and refactor your class so it depends on abstractions and not concretions that make it difficult to test the subject under test in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

Declare that your test to run async and await the response from the source class

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        ShimHttpClient shimHttpClient = new ShimHttpClient();
        ShimHttpClient.Constructor = (t) =>
        {
            shimHttpClient = new ShimHttpClient();
            await shimHttpClient.GetAsyncString = (a) =>
            {
                return new System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>(function1);
            };
        };
        var returnVal = await obj.GetYourClass();
        Assert.IsNotNull(returnVal);
        //make more assertations on the returnVal 
    }
}
```